# Can i have more than one recursive wildcard per match statement?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I read official documentation of Firebase Security Rules and I found interesting quote:

> You can have at most one recursive wildcard per match statement, but
> in version 2, you can place this wildcard anywhere in the match
> statement.

This quote from this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#version-2)

So, I can't have more than one recursive wildcard per match statement in Firebase Security Rules of any version? Or it's option available in version 1?

Comment: This is the third question in a few hours about one very specific section of the Firebase documentation. While there's always a chance that folks will answer all 3, chances will drastically go up if you show what you're trying to accomplish, [what you did already and where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and what problem you got at that point.

Comment: Sometimes in the process of reading the documentation I come across confusing wording that is difficult to understand at first. It seems to me that if there were more examples, I would not ask so many questions. Also, by the way, I noticed a large pile of terms that sometimes merge and it becomes even more difficult to read. In general, as I understand that, this is not the easiest documentation to understand).

Comment: But I understand you, I will try to describe my problem in more detail

Comment: All valid feedback, but not something that Stack Overflow is ultimately the right forum to address. If you think the Firebase documentation should be clarified, there's a link to leave feedback at the bottom of the page. That leaves the feedback with the tech writers, who are the right people to address it. And then here on Stack Overflow we can focus on the concrete problem of what you're trying to accomplish and where you are stuck

Comment: But if, for example, I'm not sure that I correctly understood the text of the documentation and I want to check my guess, Stack Overflow is not right place for this?

Comment: Firebase feedback system give me answers on my questions?